# Disable opencart admin cache

Tags: php, html, css, opencart, opencart-3

I made a copy of my opencart 3.0.3.2 website and hosted it to another server and with other domain. Now i am facing an issue that any change made on my admin panel, I have to clear my browser cache to check the changes. 
Changes like, If I created a folder in file manager it won't show up until I clear my browser cache. If I delete any product through the product manager, it will still show until I clear my browser cache.

I tried clearing SAAS and theme cache through common/dashboard.

http://whitedotsports.co.uk/admin

Comment: Maybe the new server sends different HTTP cache headers. Can you add examples of the response headers for the old and the new servers?

Comment: I have less or no knowledge of it...If you can check I can provide you with FTP details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using CloudFlare. It could cause this. on the CloudFlare dashboard go to *Cache* settings. Try to switch *Caching Level* on different positions and switch on/off *Development Mode*. And test the result.

Although you told  that you have changes hosting. You can ask hosting provider support about this case.